# Can't connect to ubuntu-ran cstrike server (27015 udp)

Tags: firewall, vps, steam, games

I've ran a Counter-Strike 1.6 Server on a Ubuntu 18 VPS.

When I run the hlds, The server looks fine when ran. (I'm running via ssh)

[image: The output of status command]

But I can't connect to it with my computer.

[image: My CS1.6 Client]

This is nmap output (X.X.X.X are my vps's ip):

```
root@vm-9538:~# nmap -sU X.X.X.X -p 27015

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-28 23:44 PDT
Nmap scan report for ip-X-X-X-X.Hosted-by.PARSVDS.com (X.X.X.X)
Host is up.

PORT      STATE         SERVICE
27015/udp open|filtered halflife

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.10 seconds
```

What should I do? Any help?

Comment: Update: Output of netstat is:  

`Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
udp    37632      0 0.0.0.0:27015           0.0.0.0:*`

Comment: It is better to update the question than adding extra information in comments. For your problem: a firewall blocking the port could be the reason.